# Photoshop Javascript - color lookup set lut

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, javascript

Say I have the lookup layer as lookup = app.currentDocument.activeLayer How can I set the setting on the layer? As far as I can tell its Art Layer base class, and I can only see base calls in my data browser (toolkit). How can I cast it to lookup/set lookup programatically?

TIA

Comment: What do you mean “set the setting on the layer”? Set **what** setting? What exactly are you trying to do? And what is “lut” supposed to be?

Comment: I want to set 3D Lut file on Color Lookup adjustment layer

Comment: You can't set it via DOM. Check the [Scripting Listener plugin](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/downloadable-plugins-and-content.html#ScriptingListenerplugin) — it'll generate some Action Manager code you could use in your JS scripts.

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy yes I have tried it. I'm afraid it does not give any output when specifying file/lut :- (

Comment: oh, tried that and you're right: it doesn't record changes. In this case I'd think it's impossible to do with a script :/